# PHP Typecasting an Int as a String - doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, casting

I am trying to calculate percentiles for users in a database. In order to do this I have a `$data` array that I need to sort.

I have a query object that contains `User_ID`, `Total_User_Orders`, and `Total_Orders`. Here's how the code looks so far:

```
// Loop through the users
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    (string)$user_id = (string)$row->user_id;

    $data[$user_id] = number_format((($row->total_user_orders/$row->total_orders)*100), 5);
}

// Sort the $data array
array_multisort($data);

print_r($data);
```

What (I believe) that should do is typecast `$row->user_id` (an int) as a string. Then, the `$data[$user_id]` index should be set as a string - right...?

**When I sort the array using `array_multisort` it sorts it as though the index was an Integer, rather than a String**. This means it loses the index.

The PHP manual for `array_multisort()` states, *"Associative (string) keys will be maintained, but numeric keys will be re-indexed."*. I have also tried using `array_multisort($data, SORT_STRING)`, but the same output occurs. However - it does work when I do `$data['#'.$user_id]`, but this doesn't quite feel like the right solution to me!

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you are trying to sort by User ID, `$data` doesn't look multi-dimensional here, why can't you use `asort()`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: No, I'm trying to sort by the value (`number_format([...])` etc). But I want to retain the user ID as a key so that I can link up the User ID with their Percentile value later on.

Comment: Having just said that... `asort()` seems to have done the trick just fine!

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean sort by user ID, that's the key, `asort()` will sort by the value of the array and maintain the association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things. With no testing, I'd think indexing the `$data`-array like this would work:

```
$data[(string)$row->user_id] = ...
```

or

```
$data[''.$user_id] = ...
```

**EDIT:**
Otherwise you could build your array multi-dimensional and sort by one of the indices, like this:

```
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
  $data[] = array(
    'user_id' => $row->user_id,
    'percent' => number_format((($row->total_user_orders/$row->total_orders)*100), 5);
  );
}
```

Or you could index by the percentage and sort by the keys (using `ksort()`):

```
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
  $data[number_format((($row->total_user_orders/$row->total_orders)*100), 5)] = $row->user_id];
}
```

The last solution could be dangerous if several users have the same percentage.

Personally I would probably go with the `asort()` solution mentioned above.

Comment: I've just tried both suggestions and I still get exactly the same output. I will edit my question to clarify what `print_r()` is outputting.

Comment: I don't think it'll work because I remember having this problem already, and when the key is a number PHP will re-index the table, even if you explicitly cast it as a string (but it's been a while and I didn't retest since).

Comment: I've updated my answer to give more ideas for solving this (and similar) problem. Depends on the specific needs which is best.

Answer (score 1):

As described in my comment, `array_multisort()` is not what you are after here. You don't have multiple arrays or a multi-dimensional array.

To maintain the `key => value` association in the array and sort the contents use [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $percent = ($row->total_user_orders / $row->total_orders) * 100;
    $data[$row->user_id] = number_format($percent, 5);
}
asort($data);
```

If you want descending percentages [reverse the array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) after it's been sorted.

```
$data = array_reverse($data, true);
```